# How to read voltage value from arduino to esp32

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32

I am learning Arduino(uno)-ESP32 basics for a hobby project. In Arduino sketch, it's writing some random value(mimicking a sensor) to Arduino analog pin 9.

```
const int analogInPin = A0;  // NOT CONNECTED
const int outPin = 9;        // DIGITAL OUT. [ESP32 INPUT]

// SETUP()
randomSeed(analogRead(analogInPin));

// LOOP()
sensorValue = random(0, 1024);
// 0 - 5v WHEN MEASURED 
// MAP VALUE OR JUST WRITE 'sensorValue' 
outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
analogWrite(outPin, outputValue);
```

In ESP32 sketch, I'm trying to read this value

```
int adc_value = 0; // EXPECTS A VALUE B/W 0 - 4095

//SETUP()
pinMode(26,INPUT);

//LOOP()
adc_value = analogRead(26);
Serial.println(adc_value);// OUTPUT 2 VALUES; 0 AND 4095
// MAP_VALUE = (adc_value * 5 ) / (4095);
```

The output is only 2 values, 0 and 4095. Is it due to ESP 3.3V and Arduino 0-5v output range or some other mistakes?

Comment: it is because analogWrite is PWM. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM

Comment: esp32 analog pin's maximum is 1 V